# What to do with my RSS sitemap & PubSubHubbub for fast URL indexation in Google?

Tags: seo, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, google-index, rss

I've read on several places, that by using **Google PubSubHubbub** will get the newest pages posted in **RSS feeds** ultra fast indexed by Google.

So, I have my RSS sitemap with lots of new pages added daily (new pages each hour).

There seem to be http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/ and https://github.com/pubsubhubbub

Question: what do I do with PubSubHubbub, and more importantly, how, so the pages from my RSS sitemap would get the fastest indexing in Google?